# Proper notation of average with a subscript

Tags: notation, average, means

When notating a mean, does the bar extend over a subscript as well? Which of these is correct?

$$\bar S_T$$

or

$$\overline {S_T}$$

Comment: The first one reads ‘(the mean of $S$) sub $T$‘. The second reads ‘the mean of ($S$ sub $T$)’. I’d say the second one makes more sense.

Comment: I agree with @Tavish on logical grounds, but it seems to me that the first is what is common, probably for typographical reasons.  This is just an impression.  I can't defend it if challenged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through some textbooks, I've consistently found that the first notation $\bar S_T$ is the correct one to use.